# JSON reviver function returns undefined even with return

Tags: javascript, json, reviver-function

```
function _quotedText(data, config) {
    var pathKeys=config.customKey;  
    console.log(pathKeys);         //prints os_platform
    var inAuth_data=(JSON.parse(JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data["event.fields.custom_fields.inauth_device_data"])), (key, value) => {
        if (key == pathKeys)
        {
            console.log(value);     //prints Android
            return value;           //returns undefined
        }
    }));

    console.log(inAuth_data);       //prints undefined
    return inAuth_data;             //returns undefined
}
```

I have read other similar questions and tried what they are doing but i still don't get it. Why is it returning undefined ?

The JSON in question here is:

```
"\"{\\\"deviceInfo\\\":{\\\"permanentId\\\":\\\"23434433-3333-4444-9581-f9cb641d28f5\\\",\\\"publicSigningKey\\\":\\\"MIIBIDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ0AMIIBCAKCAQEAzMRW6jXVgqX0QV0EA9h2XnnPvntER5yqPKvD+yLKtxXzBCYMzygEM1nlwBRZhVpNJFvzZ2X+oTLGasdbasjhddasdu0PAWIc1AqKMt6rDEJv4a8bgqqAnXXnvR/QjwtsIq3T59LqivcoB2IPGq7Mof7yRJXKtrEOK2a1b8ixWJ5MBZ06drONhMkzeDTKjenMSM0Hf3BFTlXKCFaZbfShr1OK+wMqWFYrAJsAsufvzwjxKzaZ/RspVuZtfHo0g0z7SxWRBT7+2lKGN0pFyUYebN471n5hZxVMY8Zjfr75QUK1fWIVhzNRc+pH3PhakBeqsnmNncy+XOA7TwIBEQ==\\\"},\\\"objects\\\":[{\\\"perm_id\\\":\\\"READ_PHONE_STATE_DISABLED\\\",\\\"device_pid\\\":\\\"READ_PHONE_STATE_DISABLED\\\",\\\"sdk_version\\\":\\\"Android-MME-7.8.2\\\",\\\"data\\\":{\\\"contact_info_logs\\\":[],\\\"wifi_connection_logs\\\":[{\\\"ip\\\":\\\"111.22.33.44\\\",\\\"ssid\\\":\\\"\\\\\\\"iPhone sdf Gucci\\\\\\\"\\\",\\\"linkspeed\\\":\\\"72\\\",\\\"bssid\\\":\\\"22: 56: 23: 45: 0c: ab\\\",\\\"rssi\\\":\\\"-35\\\",\\\"macaddr\\\":\\\"a4: ss: ea: 17: dg: ss\\\",\\\"networkid\\\":\\\"17\\\"}]}}]}\""
```

Comment: Why are you parsing the same data so many times? `(JSON.parse(JSON.parse(JSON.parse(`

Comment: because the data is stringified thrice ex: ""\"{\\\"deviceInfo\\\":{\\\"permanentId\\\":\\\"8f408412-6934-4bf8-9581-............

Comment: Ah, it's Mr Thrice! You shouldn't need to parse the data multiple times. It's also causing mismatched braces. Try removing all but one `JSON.parse`

Comment: tried that, "console.log(value);     //prints Android" now prints nothing.

Comment: Can you update the question with a [mcve] of the JSON?

Comment: But when I parse it thrice and do a console.log(value) it print the correct value, however when I try to return it, it return undefined!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142196/discussion-between-evolutionxbox-and-anusha).

Comment: Take a look at [this SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386685/why-would-a-return-be-undefined-but-console-log-return-an-int)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I found the solution dude, appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after a lot of head banging.
However, it seems like the function was being called for every object in the JSON. And after

> if (key == pathKeys)

was checked it printed the value and returned the value, however there were still objects in the JSON string after the matched key which were being overridden onto the variable inAuth_data.

Therefore, all I had to was declare another variable outside the reviver function and assign to it the value when the condition was true.

```
function _quotedText(data, config) {
var pathKeys=config.customKey;  
console.log(pathKeys);         //prints os_platform
var data = undefined;
var inAuth_data =(JSON.parse(JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data["event.fields.custom_fields.inauth_device_data"])), (key, value) => {
    if (key == pathKeys)
    {
        console.log(value);     //prints Android
        data = value;           //Assigning value of value to data
    }
  }));

console.log(inAuth_data);       //prints Android
return inAuth_data;             //returns Android
```

}

Thanks to @evolutionxbox for working with me on this.